# How get the bad request message in retrofit 2

Tags: asp.net-web-api, retrofit, retrofit2

My service return Status: 
400 Bad Request 
with a message: 
Invalid credentials(wrong Password)

I can see this in Postman.

The problem is that i don't know how get the 
"400 Bad Request message Invalid credentials(wrong Password)" from my android code.

Here is my code:

```java
call.enqueue(new Callback<JWToken>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<JWToken> call, Response<JWToken> response) {
        String strMsg = response.message();  // I get message "Bad Request" without the string "Invalid credentials(wrong Password)"            
    }
```

How can I get the message "Invalid credentials(wrong Password)" that my web api returns and I can see in Postman?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try looking in the [`errorBody()`](http://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/Response.html#errorBody--) of the `Response`.  Note that `errorBody` will only be non-null if `isSuccessful` is false.

```java
call.enqueue(new Callback<JWToken>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<JWToken> call, Response<JWToken> response) {
        if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
            String strMsg = response.message();
            try {
                String errorContent = response.errorBody().string();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }       
        }           
    }
```

Comment: hello,
okhttp3.ResponseBody$1@59c20fd

Comment: @VadimM  make sure you are using `.string()` and NOT `toString()`

Comment: hello, thank you for your answer
I tried,
Unfortunately I get the next string:    "okhttp3.ResponseBody$1@59c20fd"

Comment: Error:(392, 86) error: unreported exception IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown

Comment: Yes, it needs to be in the `try` and `catch` like in my answer because it is a checked exception.

Comment: try {
                        String errorContent = response.errorBody().string();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }